# Scientific Rigor

Tags: discussion

Everyone and their mothers seem to have an opinion on why minimum wages are good/bad, no matter what was asked [in the question](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/429/what-is-the-purpose-of-increasing-the-minimum-wage).

Clearly these kind of questions are attracting lots of visitors (2k views), but can we please consistently down vote questions that neither

- Use standard economic intuition to explain mechanisms
- Use non-standard economic intuition, but explicitly list assumptions of the model
- State results without explaining the mechanisms, but list references for their claims.

Comment: Yes!! Dealing with non-rigorous answers is going to be important for maintaining the integrity of the site. We don't want to lose experts because the site is overrun with low-quality posts.

Comment: Yes, and up vote the good answers to accelerate the climb above the bad ones.